# Downloading a file over the Internet using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, api, python-requests

I am trying to use YouTubeinMp3's API to write a script which will download the music file on sending a request to a particular endpoint.

```
import requests
import json

si = {'video': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTgLhIjiSas', 'autostart': 1}
res = requests.get("https://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/", params = si)
print len(res.content)
```

Now, the resulting URL ie `https://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/?video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTgLhIjiSas&autostart=1` automatically starts downloading the corresponding mp3 file of the given video.

However, on executing the above script, the file does not start downloading. The `status_code` returned is `200`. What seems to be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generated URL leads to a HTML page, that redirects you to another page, that triggers a download. This URL is not a direct URL to the mp3 file itself. To get the mp3's URL you can scrape those pages.

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'])
```

Before you run the above you'll need to install the youtube_dl package using pip.
Open up your terminal/cmd and type:

```
pip install youtube_dl
```